# Scala - class is broken

Tags: java, class, scala

I am trying to build a project that has an external dependency on one of the jars. I have a Java version of the class that uses class X from the jar and that builds fine. As soon as I try to build taht using scala, I am getting an error that the "class X is broken" followed by NullPointerExcpetion. What might be the reason for it?

Comment: What you using to build/compile scala class? can you add error output to question?

Answer (score 2):

You have a broken dependency on your **`MANIFEST`** file. Add the dependency of that X class and try again.

Comment: Would you mind explaining that a bit more? I am using IVY as a dependency resolver, pointing at locally disted area. All the jars seem to be there, and Java, as I said, compiles without problems, pointing exactly to the same thing

Comment: Does your class X inherit from a static Java inner class?

Comment: No, it inherits from a lot of other dependencies internally

Comment: Just FYI, I found this: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2464 . This bug is pretty actual and may have some relation with your problem (if you do have all dependencies listed and ok)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your external dependency itself depending on something external. This way builder can not make a whole class, so it is reporting you that class or jar is broken.

Comment: How come the Java builds then?

Comment: Maybe because it has this dependency via some classpath import. It is really hard to tell without compiler output.